# Reverse for 'about' with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I'm attempting to Django, and I've gotten a few urls working but one set just wont work.

It keeps asking for a argument but it shouldn't require one.

Error below.

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'about' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$about/']

Error during template rendering

In template hub\templates\partials\footer.html, error at line 33
```

hub\templates\partials\footer.html line 33

```
<a href="{% url 'hub:about' %}" class="nav__link">About</a>
```

hub/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^about/', views.AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.ContactPageView.as_view(), name='contact'),
]
```

storyarchive/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('hub.urls', namespace='hub')),
    url(r'^community/', include('community.urls', namespace='community')),
    url(r'^forum/', include('forum.urls', namespace='forum')),
    url(r'^story/', include('story.urls', namespace='story')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

It worked before I started to use the `{% url %}` builtin.

Django Version:     1.11.5
Python Version:     3.4.4

Comment: you should define the url pattern for `'hub:about'`.

Comment: Sorry about that I edited it in.

Comment: can you share your whole content of hub/urls.py?

Comment: @Tiny.D I edited both files in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` from your urlpattern which includes `hub.urls`. That only matches with an empty string. So it won't get matched with `about`.
Thats why it shows `$about/` in your error log too. Change your `storyarchive/urls.py` like this:

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
 from django.contrib import admin

 urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^', include('hub.urls', namespace='hub')),
  url(r'^community/', include('community.urls', namespace='community')),
  url(r'^forum/', include('forum.urls', namespace='forum')),
  url(r'^story/', include('story.urls', namespace='story')),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it, somehow I change every urlpattern expect that one.